# Sql Laravel query, need to correct the result

Tags: mysql, laravel, datatables

```
 $tglA = Carbon::create($request->tglA)->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d');
            $tglB = Carbon::create($request->tglB)->lastOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d');
            $tglHari = Carbon::create($request->tglA)->lastOfMonth()->format('d');
            $period = CarbonPeriod::create($tglA, $tglB)->toArray();


$scoreboard = HistoryPenjualan::select('kodeSales', 'departemenId');
                        for ($count = 1; $count <= $tglHari; $count++){
                            $dateFormat = $period[$count-1]->format('Y-m-d');
                            $scoreboard->selectRaw("SUM(CASE WHEN tgl = '$dateFormat' THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS '$count'");
                        };
                        $scoreboard->whereBetween('tgl', [$tglA, $tglB])
                        ->where('departemenId', $request->departemenId)
                        ->groupBy('departemenId')
                        ->get();
```

I am using Laravel 6 and using datatables for this, the score suppose to get only up to the last day of the month so January until 31 but instead i got :

```
{
  "0": "22108",
  "1": "65423",
  "2": "88415",
  "3": "37753",
  "4": "48535",
  "5": "94345",
  "6": "100010",
  "7": "52653",
  "8": "134070",
  "9": "65670",
  "10": "80811",
  "11": "104003",
  "12": "93135",
  "13": "56480",
  "14": "40196",
  "15": "82316",
  "16": "83951",
  "17": "86533",
  "18": "66981",
  "19": "85343",
  "20": "163440",
  "21": "46295",
  "22": "93169",
  "23": "112213",
  "24": "82673",
  "25": "49780",
  "26": "49590",
  "27": "73993",
  "28": "68630",
  "29": "103523",
  "30": "0",
  "31": "22108",
  "32": "65423",
  "33": "88415",
  "34": "37753",
  "35": "48535",
  "36": "94345",
  "37": "100010",
  "38": "52653",
  "39": "134070",
  "40": "65670",
  "41": "80811",
  "42": "104003",
  "43": "93135",
  "44": "56480",
  "45": "40196",
  "46": "82316",
  "47": "83951",
  "48": "86533",
  "49": "66981",
  "50": "85343",
  "51": "163440",
  "52": "46295",
  "53": "93169",
  "54": "112213",
  "55": "82673",
  "56": "49780",
  "57": "49590",
  "58": "73993",
  "59": "68630",
  "60": "103523",
  "61": "0",
  "kodeSales": "1776",
  "departemenId": 28,
  "action": "null",
  "karyawan": "null",
  "cabang": "null",
  "score": null,
  "DT_RowIndex": 1
}
```

it goes until 61 and at 30th and 61th it give 0 (January 30 supposedly has value in it), how to make it only up to last day of the month and only give the value up to there ?

Comment: You may need to provide an example of the request variables `$request->tglA` and `$request->tglB`. What do you get if you `dd($period)`?

Comment: @SteveO  `$request->tglA` and `$request->tglB`, is a Month range formatted `('F Y')`, already did `dd($period)` like you said it give the first of january until end of january (basically what i want) but its index start from 0

Comment: which should be correct since i do `$dateFormat = $period[$count-1]->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: Ahh okay i found out that 31 january doesnt have value but i mistake it that it was 30 january since the index start at 0

but the question still remain why till 61

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the format of `$request->tglA` to `Carbon`:

```
$tglHari = Carbon::createFromFormat('F Y', $request->tglA)->lastOfMonth()->format('d');
```